# Values not passing from a JList to another JList

Tags: java, arrays, swing, move, jlist

Here's my code. 
Why the values are not going into the second JList?
Also, the second Jlist is not visible.
All imports are in place and not visible in the following code:

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JList l;
    private JList l2;
    private JButton b1;
    public String [] cd = {"Album a", "Album b", "Album c", "Album d","Album e", "Album f", "Album g", "Album h"}; 

    public Gui(){

    super("Mover");
    l = new JList (cd);
    l.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    b1 = new JButton("Move");

    b1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    l2.setListData(l.getSelectedValuesList());
                }
            }
);


    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(l));
    add(b1);
    add(new JScrollPane(l2));

}
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: You never initialize `l2`. Add `l2 = new JList()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `JList l2` is null, You need to initialise it to before you can use it like you do with `l`

Add

```
l2 = new JList (/*your list2 or empty*/);
```

just after your initialisation of the `JList l`

**Edit** As I now see was mentioned in the comments